# Printing Values in an Array in Reverse

Tags: java, arrays, methods, logic

My code is designed to print the values if the array in order and then reverse order. However, I also have to At a minimum use the following method headers when writing your methods:

```
public static int printOriginalArray(int[] list)
public static int printInReverse(int[] list)
```

I got the code running! I get it now!! It just clicked!! Yes!!! :-) Now my method is not exactly accurate though correct? I should have 2 methods instead of 1 and I need to rewrite it so it reverses the numbers, not swaps.

```
public class Assignment01a {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

         int[] numbers = {4, 5, 6, 7};
         System.out.println("The list in order is: ");

         for (int num: numbers)
         System.out.println(num + " ");

         swap(numbers, 0, 3);

         for (int num: numbers)
         System.out.println(num + " ");
    }

    public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr [i] = arr [j];
        arr [j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything in your `main` method, so of course nothing will happen.

Comment: You are not calling the method in main.

Comment: That is what I'm so confused about. How do I implement the main method and have other methods within it?

Comment: Your `main()` is **empty**.  So your program does nothing.

Comment: Please read a basic java tutorial.

Comment: You seem to have most of the code that should be inside your main method inside the swap method, as well. For an explanation of what methods and classes are and how they relate, read a tutorial, as Sotirios says above. (Just search "java tutorial methods".) Or a Java textbook.

Comment: So should I put those methods in a different class file?

Comment: For this assignment a single class is enough.

Comment: If someone could give me an example of various methods implemented within the main method I would appreciate it. I'm still lost

Answer (score 1):

First, all methods need to be declared inside some class. Here, your `swap` method is being declared inside the `Assignment01a` class. Furthermore, there are static methods, which are declared by having the `static` keyword after the `public` keyword (as you have for your `swap` method). A static method can be called from `main()` directly (from a "static context") . Non-static methods however need to be invoked on/from object instances. These are methods without the `static` keyword and they can be thought of as belonging to a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I corrected it the way you wanted it to work. Since your methods are declared so that they return int value I assumed it's for error checking. If method returns anything but 0 program will let you know something went wrong. It looks like this:

```
public class Assignment01a {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

         int[] numbers = {4, 5, 6, 7};

         if (printOriginalArray(numbers) != 0)
             System.out.println("ERROR!");

         if (printInReverse(numbers) != 0)
             System.out.println("ERROR!");

         System.out.println("\nProgram completed successfully!");

    }

    public static int printOriginalArray(int[] list) {

        System.out.println("The list in order is: ");

         for (int num: list)
         System.out.print(num + " ");

         return 0;

    }

    public static int printInReverse(int[] list) {

        System.out.println("\nThe list in reverse order is:");

        for (int i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        return 0;

    }

}
```

I hope that clarified your problem, if you have any other question feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes this definitely helped a lot! Would it be hard now to implement the original array as a separate method so the program would have 1 method for the original array and 1 method for the reverse? Thank youuu soo much!

Comment: No it wouldn't, I'll edit my comment the way I got it you want methods to work, if I got anything wrong please correct me.